# RadChartView not showing line series

Tags: wpf, xaml, charts, telerik, mahapps.metro

I have a simple `RadChartView` on a `UserControl`. When I add a series, it doesn't appear and I don't know why. Does anyone have the same issue? I think it is a style issue, because we are using `mahapps.metro` in our app.

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="300"  MinHeight="250" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" 
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 0 10 0">
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.EmptyContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="En attente des données..." Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.EmptyContentTemplate>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <telerik:LinearAxis Title="{Binding BondSecondes}" />
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerik:LinearAxis Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding CompteurMaximum}" MajorStep="5" Visibility="Visible" />
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
            <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="XY" />
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
            <telerik:LineSeries Stroke="Red" ShowLabels="True" >
                <telerik:LineSeries.DataPoints>
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="50" Value="2" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="48" Value="5" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="46" Value="6" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="44" Value="6" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="42" Value="15" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="40" Value="6" />
                    <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="38" Value="1" />
                </telerik:LineSeries.DataPoints>
            </telerik:LineSeries>
            <!--<telerik:LineSeries CategoryBinding="Seconde" ValueBinding="Compte" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphDemandes}">
                <telerik:LineSeries.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="telerik:LineSeries">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                    </Style>
                </telerik:LineSeries.Style>
            </telerik:LineSeries>
            <telerik:LineSeries CategoryBinding="Seconde" ValueBinding="Compte" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphVertNaturels}" Stroke="{Binding CouleurVertNaturel}" StrokeThickness="3"/>
            <telerik:LineSeries CategoryBinding="Seconde" ValueBinding="Compte" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphAcceptees}" Stroke="{Binding CouleurAcceptee}" StrokeThickness="3"/>
            <telerik:LineSeries CategoryBinding="Seconde" ValueBinding="Compte" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphRejetees}" Stroke="{Binding CouleurRejetee}" StrokeThickness="3" />-->
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

Does someone have the same issue and have a solution?

Print screen of my graphic :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, if someone make the same error as me, it is just because I was not using the good series for my case. I needed two vertical axis of type LinearAxis, but to do that, my series need to be of type **ScatterLineSeries**. I recommand to consult this page to use the right combinaison for your graphic :
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/series-and-axes